# UITableView in Storyboard appears empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

It's my first time using Storyboard to build an app. I'm trying to create a UITableView with a custom cell. I've created the cell in IB and created a custom tableViewCell class for it (added some labels, created appropriate outlets, connected them in IB and assigned the custom class to the custom cell in IB).

In the ViewController responsible for the TableView I create the data source (a dict with some arrays) and fill out all the obligatory methods (I've tried both with UITableViewControler and with a UIViewController that is set as a delegate and data source for the tableview)

And when I run the app - the tableview is empty. And after doing some NSLogging I've noticed that the data source methods are never executed. And I have NO IDEA why.

I'm going crazy about this for a few hours now. Please help me out :)

Let me know if you need to see the code or Storyboard, or whatever else.

**UPDATE:** Alright, after some digging, I've decided to test out the same code but using an NSMutableArray as data source instead of a NSMutableDictionary. And it works! 
Now, could someone explain to me why it didn't work with a dict?

Here's what did. I had a dict with 5 arrays, and each array had 5 strings.

In the numberOfRowsForSection method, I returned [dict count]

And in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I've used this code

```
NSArray * routeArray = [dealsDict objectForKey:@"route"];
cell.routeName.text = [routeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray * companyArray = [dealsDict objectForKey:@"company"];
cell.companyName.text = [companyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray * priceArray = [dealsDict objectForKey:@"price"];
cell.priceLabel.text = [priceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray * dateArray = [dealsDict objectForKey:@"date"];
cell.dateLabel.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray * monthArray = [dealsDict objectForKey:@"month"];
cell.monthLabel.text = [monthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"I'm in here");

return cell;
```

why didn't it want to show anything?

Comment: Did you set the Custom Class in Interface Builder to be your class that implements the `UITableViewDataSource` methods?

Answer (score 0):

In the IB, select your table view, and make sure that the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets are set for your controller

Comment: Done that when I tried it with a simple UIViewController. Didn't work. It also appears empty when I use a UITableViewController (which by default is declared as the datasource)

Answer (score 0):

UITableView need some collection dataset as data source. Its delegate method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" get called equals to number of elements of collection (ARRAY). like numberOfRowsInSection delegate tells the table view that it need to call cellForRowAtIndexPath for every element in collection. and it also need some iterator to read each time the next element, in case of dictionary it always stick to same data element at each call of cellForRowAtIndexPath. I hope it wil give you the idea of its working, Please let me know if you need anything else to know.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [self.data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
  MessagesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"messageCellIdentifier"];

  Message *msg = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.Name.text = msg.Name;
  cell.Message.text = msg.MessageText;
  cell.Time.text = msg.Time;

  return cell;
}
```